# How to split a user input coordinate and use in calculations?

Tags: python, input, split

I am trying to calculate the radius of a circle using 2 points given by the user.
The program works with a simple single integer entry like this ...

```
x1 = int(input("enter x1"))
y1 = int(input("enter y1"))
```

But I wanted to write the input in a way that allows the user to enter a point like this...

```
2,5
```

Below is the code for the program, it will accept the user
input of x1,y1 and x2,y2, but the calculations are coming out as 0.0.

What am I missing?

```
import math

def distance (x1,y1,x2,y2):
    dis = math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
    return distance

def radius (x1,y1,x2,y2):
    rad = distance(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    return rad

def main():

coordinate_1 = input("enter x1 and y1")
    coordinate_1 = coordinate_1.split(",") 
    x1 = int(coordinate_1[0])
    y1 = int(coordinate_1[1])

    coordinate_2 = input("enter x2 and y2")
    coordinate_2 = coordinate_2.split(",") 
    x2 = int(coordinate_1[0])
    y2 = int(coordinate_1[1])

    rad = radius(x1,y1,x2,y2)

    print("the radius is:", rad)

main()
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code hangs waiting for input -- don't expect us to enter test data, or to build a test file.
Instead, simply hard-code a test case that causes the problem.

Comment: [eval is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not shared complete working code, but if you're having an output of 0.0, it is because of the following lines of code:

```
x2 = int(coordinate_1[0])
y2 = int(coordinate_1[1])
```

You are using the first input coordinate for x2 and y2, and so the distance between them results to be 0.0.

You ought to update the above lines to:

```
x2 = int(coordinate_2[0])
y2 = int(coordinate_2[1])
```

Below I have shared complete code with modifications and after resolving errors (on your original code), that works:

```
import math

def calc_distance(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    dis = math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
    return dis

def calc_radius(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    rad = calc_distance(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    return rad

coordinate_1 = eval(input("enter x1 and y1"))
x1 = int(coordinate_1[0])
y1 = int(coordinate_1[1])

print(x1, y1)

coordinate_2 = eval(input("enter x2 and y2"))
x2 = int(coordinate_2[0])
y2 = int(coordinate_2[1])

radius = calc_radius(x1, y1, x2, y2)

print("the radius is:", radius)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like that to get a list of the coordinate

```py
input1='2,5'
a = input1.split(',')
a=list(map(int,a))
print(a)
# [2, 5]
```